# why I use include_directories failed?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile, g++

I attempt to include the third-party lib in the CmakeLists.txt, but I feel confused about the difference between "include_directories" and "target_link_libraries" .

I get the main difference is the directory scope.

But I always got error in using "include_directories".

And when I use the "target_link_libraries" it will be correct.

Does I do something wrong?

Here is the file and the error message:
[screenpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHl5D.png)

Comment: You're simply using the incorrect include directory. I assume the boost headers are located in a subdirectory called `include` which is missing from the include directories. The use of `target_include_directories` is preferrable to `include_directories` btw, but it would be best to use the cmake package configuration script your boost installation should come with via `find_package` and link the imported cmake target provided by the package; this imported target should come with the information about the correct include directories attached.

Comment: Yeah,I found this problem before going to bed, what a foolish question.